# How do cards with "X" work?

Tags: slay-the-spire

I couldn't find any explanation inside the game. Maybe it's the number of the turns passed since the beginning of the current combat?

Comment: It takes roughly two tries to understand how they work. Second try is when you have 0 energy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [answer](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Energy) is:

> Some cards can have X Energy cost. These cards consume all of your
>   remaining Energy upon use, and their effect varies with how much
>   Energy was consumed.